# wp core install cannot connect to database with WP-CLI

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, wp-cli

I don't know why it's doing this but for some reason, when I try to install WordPress with WP CLI with `wp core install`, it cannot complete and throws the `Error: Error establishing a database connection` error.

I've checked everything and I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm using MAMP PRO and all of the settings in the `wp-config.php` file are correct.

I'm connecting via `localhost` and the database is created just fine and I can see that there.

I've tried changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in the `wp-config` file, but that borks outright.

Username and Password to connect are the default of `root` and `root`.

If I go to the local URL directly, I can see the WP install screen and then after I select the language, it redirects me to the setup where I can name the site, username, password, etc. I never see the DB connection info at all.

I did have to set this in my `.zshrc` file:
`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/` cause it was having an issue when creating the `wp-config` file with `wp config create`, but once I added that, it was able to create the `wp-config` file without errors, so maybe that might be an issue?  But overall, I'm stumped. I had a bash script that was working to generate all of this automatically, but now I'm not sure what the issue could be since it appears everything is setup correctly.

Comment: Which ports did you configure MAMP PRO to use for the database?

Comment: @leymannx - AH, I just checked and it looks like mysql was set to 8889. Gonna try setting it to 3306 and see what happens.

Comment: This or `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8889');` or `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');`.

Comment: This is what worked for me `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' );`

Answer (score 4):

If you're running on Mac and using MAMP, update hostname in wp-config.php

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' );
```